# Why kinetic energy become half when you double the mass of a moving object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

If a body moving with velocity V and having kinetic energy 1/2 mv2 , if I put a objecf of mass m on it , why does kinetic energy become half ??

Comment: What happens to the momentum?

Comment: Conserved  as there is no external force

Comment: This is like an inelastic collision. Energy is lost to deformation, heat, noise etc.